# What is ObservableValue in LiveChart

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

I do not understand ObservableValue, or what is the difference between passing in an ObservableValue and passing in the original value/type itself?

If I take the following as an example, be it ObservableValue or a double type, the Chart would dynamically populate the random value and update the chart including the animation.

So why ObservableValue? And could someone suggest an example.

```
Values = new ChartValues<ObservableValue>
{
    new ObservableValue(r.Next(10, 400)),
};

Values = new ChartValues<double>
{
    (r.Next(10, 400)),
};
```

Comment: [ObservableValue Documentation](https://lvcharts.net/App/documentation/beta/wpf/LiveCharts-Defaults-ObservableValue): An already configured chart point, this class notifies the chart to update every time the value property changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to update an individual value within the `Values` collection dynamically at runtime after you have populated the initial collection and displayed the chart, you need to use `ObservableValue` for the chart to be able to notify this update and update itself accordingly.

There is no event raised when you simply replace a `double` value in the collection like this:

```
Values[0] = 1.0;
```

...but if you set the `Value` property of an `ObservableValue` like this, a `PropertyChanged` event is raised:

```
Values[0].Value = 1.0;
```

The chart subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event to listen for updates. That's the difference.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an `ObservableValue`, it simply notifies the chart to update every time its `Value` property changes (since it implemtents `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface).

You can find `ObservableValue` source [here](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/blob/master/Core/Defaults/ObservableValue.cs)